# Which screen size should be if only one size is going to be targeted?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is bootstrap 3 code defining a grid:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Box 3</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Box 5</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Box 6</p></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The grid above is targeted for both small and medium screen. If one and only one screen size is going to be targeted, what it would be (col-xs, sm or md)? What happen if the page is displayed on screen whose size is different from what is targeted?

Our app is used primary on desktop and occasionally on smartphone or pad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practices for responsive apps is "code for small" and make minor adjustments if necessary for bigger screens so the answer probably should be sm.

"What happen if the page is displayed on screen whose size is different from what is targeted? "

The framework should adjust accordingly. You are saying that your app will basically be a desktop used occasionally on a phone or tablet but when you run into issues down the road with screen real estate it is much easier to file small content on a large screen that to cram large content onto a small screen.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `col-sm-*` then it is automaticaly applicable for `col-md-*` and `col-lg-*` So I suggest to use `col-sm-*` if that site is more used from tablets and desktops and not from very small mobile devices.